# How to convert aa array into JSON with sample json object in java script

Tags: javascript, json, parsing, npm, formatting

I have a list of values and a sample json object. How can i convert the values in the list in the same format of my sample json object.

EX:

```
list = [true,zen,samuel,35]
sample json = {succefullresponse : "false",
carname : "swift" ,
owner : {name : "Robert", 
age : "40"
}}
```

i want the json to be printed as

```
{succefullresponse : "true",
carname : "zen" ,
owner : {name : "samuel", 
age : "35"
}
```

Comment: first, convert the array data into an object with the appropriate property names, then you can use JSON.stringify on that object .... e.g. `let props = [succefullresponse, carname, name, age] = list, obj = {succefullresponse, carname, owner : {name, age}}, json = JSON.stringify(obj);`

Comment: @JaromandaX You should post it as an answer